# Mongo error: field names cannot start with $ [$set]

Tags: mongodb, updates

That's probably very simple mistake, but I cannot find it. Running this simple query:

```
db.getCollection('thoughts').update(
  {space: {type: 'list'}},
  {space: {type: {$set: 'arrangement'}}}
);
```

I get this error:

> Error: field names cannot start with $ [$set] :
>   DBCollection.prototype._validateForStorage@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:185:1
>   DBCollection.prototype._validateForStorage@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:189:13
>   DBCollection.prototype._validateForStorage@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:189:13
>   DBCollection.prototype._validateUpdateDoc@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:416:9
>   Bulk/findOperations.updateOne@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:675:9
>   DBCollection.prototype.update@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:483:13
>   @(shell):1:1

I work with Mongo v3.2.6 and Robomongo 1.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.thoughts.update(
  { "space.type": "list" },
  { $set: { "space.type": "arrangement" } }
);
```

Notice that for updating multiple documents, you should set the `multi` option to true:

```
db.thoughts.update(
   { "space.type": "list" },
   { $set: { "space.type": "arrangement" } },
   { multi: true }
);
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! Construction written by me has been working in `react-addons-update`, which confused me, because these syntaxes are very similar.

Comment: Great to hear that :)